# Gerar uma string com letras e números aleatórios no PHP (UUID)

Tags: php

Eu criei um código em php que gera um nome com letras e números aleatórios (como um UUID), algo do tipo: *7a299248-fd87-4c42-b37d-a6e50a360d10*. Mas eu vejo que não tem um bom desempenho em relação a execução do código! Como posso fazer para melhorar o desempenho?

```
$filename = substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 8)
    . "-" . substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 4)
    . "-" . substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 4)
    . "-" . substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 4)
    . "-" . substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 10);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Supondo que esteja querendo gerar um UUID, esse código só funciona em PHP 7 ou maior

[random_bytes — Gera bytes pseudo-aleatórios criptograficamente seguros](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-bytes)

```
function uuid(){
    $data = random_bytes(16);
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); 
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); 
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
```

ou:
https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: Muito obrigado!